# Netsuite emails > IF statement for custom fields

Tags: email, if-statement, customization, netsuite

**Details:** Custom field: Sub Item | Custom field ID: entity18

I'm trying to display **values of a custom field** in an email. When I type **${customer.entity18} in the email**, it shows the right value.

However, I want to write an IF statement. Something like this:
<#if (customer.entity18) == "Hello"> HTML </#if>

But I'm clearly missing out something, because this IF statement isn't working. Any recommendations?

Comment: What "isn't working"?  What's your expected outcome?  What's the actual behavior?  What's the value of `customer.entity18`?  Also, have you tried `<#if customer.entity18 == "Hello">` without the parentheses?

Comment: Thanks Krypton.

I've tried a whole bunch of variations. Like: <#if (customrecord.entity18) == Hello> Online </#if> | <#if customrecord.entity18 == "Hello"> Online </#if> and much more. 

I tried your method as well, and it simply doesn't show anything in the email preview. It's just a blank space. 

The custom field's name is Subscription item and it's ID is: entity18
It's value is a subscription item's short form. I want it to say, that if this field has 'XYZ' then display Online.

Comment: Hang on...is it `customer` or `customrecord` you need to access?  Custom record types are denoted by an id starting with `customrecord` and then whatever unique-to-your-account identifier.  Custom *fields* on such records have `custrecord` and then a field id.  So `customrecord.entity18` appears to be an invalid id - could this be the source of your problems?  Accessing a field on a custom record would look something like `customrecord_my_record_type.custrecord_my_field`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax fo IF statement is

```
<#if record.customfield_id == "Hello"> HTML </#if>
```

All custom fields have a prefix in their script ID so it is not possible to create a custom field with the field ID entity18. Doublecheck your field ID to be sure you are using the right one. Here is an article on how to find it.  https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10308/kw/field%20id

Let's say you are referring to the custom field from a Customer record. Your ID could be  custentity8 where "custentity" is the prefix. Then your IF statement could look like this

```
<#if customer.custentity8 == "Hello"> HTML </#if>
```

Note that the IF statement is ignored in the email preview and you can see the result after merging the email.